# How to extend props for Material-UI components using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I would like to extend the props of the Button component from Material-UI using typescript to be able pass additional props to it's children.

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Button } from 'material-ui';

<Button
  component={NavLink}

  // NavLink props that needs to be added to typescript declarations
  activeClassName={classes.activeButton}
  exact={true}
  to={to}
>
  {title}
</Button>
```

I've tried to add the following declarations in ./app/types/material_ui.d.ts:

```
declare module 'material-ui' {
  interface Button {
    activeClassName?: any;
    exact?: boolean;
    to?: string;
  }
}
```

Which throws the error "TS2693: 'Button' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.".

I've also tried the declaration:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { PropTypes, StyledComponent } from 'material-ui';
import { ButtonBaseProps } from 'material-ui/ButtonBase';

declare module 'material-ui' {
  export interface ButtonProps extends ButtonBaseProps {
    color?: PropTypes.Color | 'contrast';
    component?: React.ReactNode;
    dense?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
    disableFocusRipple?: boolean;
    disableRipple?: boolean;
    fab?: boolean;
    href?: string;
    raised?: boolean;
    type?: string;

    activeClassName?: any;
    exact?: boolean;
    to?: string;
  }

  export class Button extends StyledComponent<ButtonProps> { }
}
```

Which throws the error "TS2323: Cannot redeclare exported variable 'Button'".

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {      
      "history": ["./node_modules/@types/history/index"],
      "redux": ["./node_modules/@types/redux/index"],
      "react": ["./node_modules/@types/react/index"],
      "*": ["./app/types/*", "*"]
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

Finally the original type definition from Material-UI:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyledComponent, PropTypes } from '..';
import { ButtonBaseProps } from '../ButtonBase';

export interface ButtonProps extends ButtonBaseProps {
  color?: PropTypes.Color | 'contrast';
  component?: React.ReactNode;
  dense?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  disableFocusRipple?: boolean;
  disableRipple?: boolean;
  fab?: boolean;
  href?: string;
  raised?: boolean;
  type?: string;
}

export default class Button extends StyledComponent<ButtonProps> {}
```

I am using material-ui 1.0.0-beta.8 with react 15.6.1, react-router-dom 4.2.2 and typescript 2.5.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code works for me

```
import { Button, StyledComponent } from 'material-ui';
import { ButtonProps } from 'material-ui/Button';

declare module 'material-ui' {
  export interface MyProps {

    exact?: boolean;
    to?: string;
  }
  export class Button extends StyledComponent<ButtonProps & MyProps> {
  }

}
```

I don't have the problem with `"TS2693: 'Button' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` and I'm also using Typescript 2.5.2

Comment: Looks pretty simple, but for me this doesn't work. I get the following errors:
**TS2323: Cannot redeclare exported variable 'Button'.**
**TS2484: Export declaration conflicts with exported declaration of 'Button'.**

Maybe this is related to [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17547).
Any idea?

Comment: interesting, here is another [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16803) about it, could you create a minimal reproducible repo?

Comment: @eitido I know it's been two years, but for anyone else that comes here, the reason is Button is a MUI component and you're trying to create your own Button component, so it's a naming  conflict. You just need to alias MUI's button as `MuiButton` (or something else).

Comment: It just doesnt' work. Did it work for anyone else?

Answer (score 25):

A bit late, but here is another solution. See also the MUI docs [Usage of component prop](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-component-prop)
.
The following button uses the Link component. It allso uses the Link's specific props with their types. It allso adds its own sesific props.

```
import React from 'react'
import MuiButton, {ButtonProps} from '@material-ui/core/Button'

interface ButtonOptions {
  // your custom options with their types
}

const Button = <C extends React.ElementType>(props: ButtonProps<C, {component?: C}> & ButtonOptions ) => {
  return <MuiButton {...props}>{props.children}</MuiButton>
}

export default Button
     
// use like this:  
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
<Button component={Link} to={'/somelocation'}>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally someone covered how to support the `component` property

Answer (score 14):

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

import { Button, ButtonProps } from '@material-ui/core';

interface IProps extends ButtonProps {} // your custom props

const ButtonHco: FC<IProps> = ({
  variant,
  color,
  children,
  size,
  disabled
}) => {
  return (
    <Button variant={variant} color={color} size={size} disabled={disabled}>
      {children}
    </Button>
  );
};

export default ButtonHco;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Somebody knows where to find and extract default values for Box'es "justifyContent" property?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a minimalistic sample of extending a Material UI Button (untested).
The extended field will be simply appended after the button label.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ButtonProps } from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

interface Props{
  extendedField: string;
}

export class MyExtendedButton extends React.Component<ButtonProps & Props>{
  render(){

    const {
      extendedField,
      children,
      ...buttonProps,
    } = this.props;

    return (<Button {...buttonProps}>
      {children}
      : <span style={{color: 'red'}}>
        {extendedField}
      </span>
    </Button>);
  }
}
```

Comment: So helpful, thanks for sharing a class-based example :)