# Extend material-ui component in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Trying to extend the Material-ui Button component to add new props.

Purpose is to add a new prop: `fontSize` which has three options - `small`, `medium`, `large`.

> ```
> <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" fontSize="small">
>     button_small
> </Button>
> ```

and to use it in css to make the required changes.

As per the material ui documentation for [typescript theme customisation](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#typescript), I have already customised the theme and it works fine.

Only problem is trying to update the prop types for Button doesn't work.

And I get this error for no overload match which is obvious because material ui Button component doesn't know about the "fontSize" new props.

> error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
>
> Overload 1 of 3, '(props: { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode;
> color?: Color | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined;
> disableElevation?: boolean | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean |
> undefined; ... 5 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... |
> undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element',
> gave the following error. Type '{ children: string; variant:
> "outlined"; color: "primary"; fontSize: string; }' is not assignable
> to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { children?:
> ReactNode; color?: Color | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined;
> disableElevation?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; variant?:
> "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> &
> Pick<...>'. Property 'fontSize' does not exist on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode;
> color?: Color | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined;
> disableElevation?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; variant?:
> "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> &
> Pick<...>'.
>
> Overload 2 of 3, '(props: { component: ElementType; } & {
> children?: ReactNode; color?: Color | undefined; disabled?: boolean |
> undefined; disableElevation?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...;
> variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } &
> CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
> Property 'component' is missing in type '{ children: string; variant:
> "outlined"; color: "primary"; fontSize: string; }' but required in
> type '{ component: ElementType; }'.
>
> Overload 3 of 3, '(props:
> DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<ButtonTypeMap<{},
> "button">>>): Element', gave the following error. Type '{ children:
> string; variant: "outlined"; color: "primary"; fontSize: string; }' is
> not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode;
> color?: Color | undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined;
> disableElevation?: boolean | undefined; ... 6 more ...; variant?:
> "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> &
> Pick<...>'. Property 'fontSize' does not exist on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; color?: Color |
> undefined; disabled?: boolean | undefined; disableElevation?: boolean
> | undefined; ... 6 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... |
> undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'.

Attempt 1:
Following the answer from [this stack-overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46175082/2860486)  I tried to redeclare the Button, but it throws a typescript error (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17547) which seems to be unresolved.

```
declare module '@material-ui/core' {
    export interface MyButtonProps {
        fontSize: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
    }
    export class Button extends StyledComponent<ButtonProps & MyProps> {
    }
}
```

Attempt2:
Trying to overwrite the ButtonTypeMap instead of the Button but that doesn't help either.

```
declare module '@material-ui/core/Button' {
    export type ButtonTypeMap<P = {}, D extends React.ElementType<any> = "button"> = ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<{
        props: P & {
            children?: React.ReactNode;
            color?: CustomColors;
            disabled?: boolean;
            disableElevation?: boolean;
            disableFocusRipple?: boolean;
            endIcon?: React.ReactNode;
            fullWidth?: boolean;
            href?: string;
            size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
            startIcon?: React.ReactNode;
            variant?: 'text' | 'contained';
            fontSize: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large';
        };
        defaultComponent: D;
        classKey: ButtonClassKey;
    }>
    // The next line throws error with 'Button' is already declared in the upper scope
    // declare const Button: ExtendButtonBase<ButtonTypeMap>;
}
```

Versions:

typescript: `4.2.4`

@material-ui/core: `4.11.4`

Edit: There are a few answers here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65344567/2860486) which adds a Custom HOC which extends material-ui component to achieve desired behaviour but I want to overwrite the material UI component itself just to be consistent with importing component from "`material-ui`" not from my local custom-component folder.

Edit 2: I was lucky to migrate the project from version 4 to version 5 where this problem has been solved already. If you're stuck at version 4 (and upgrade is not an option) then adding a HOC is your best option.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use `ButtonProps` and extend it and add your custom properties along with speading all the rest properties.

#### The custom Button component

```
import {
  Button as MuiButton,
  ButtonProps,
  makeStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";

interface IButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  fontSize?: "small" | "medium" | "large";
}

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  small: {
    fontSize: "0.7em"
  },
  medium: {
    fontSize: "1.0em"
  },
  large: {
    fontSize: "1.4em"
  }
});

function Button({ fontSize = "medium", children, ...rest }: IButtonProps) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <MuiButton classes={{ label: classes[fontSize] }} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </MuiButton>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

You'll have every prop of MUI Button to auto complete along with your custom props like `fontSize`:

```
<div className="buttons">
  <Button
    fontSize="small"
    variant="contained"
    onClick={() => console.log("small button")}
  >
    Small
  </Button>
  <Button
    fontSize="medium"
    variant="contained"
    onClick={() => console.log("medium button")}
  >
    Medium
  </Button>
  <Button
    fontSize="large"
    variant="contained"
    onClick={() => console.log("large button")}
  >
    Large
  </Button>
</div>
```

### Result

[image: Custom Props MUI Button]

You can try the working example with full code completetion at this [CodeSandBox React TS Demo App](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ts-mui-extend-button-x60yc).

PS: If you use ESLint, don't forget to allow JSX Props Spreading by disabling the rule [`react/jsx-props-no-spreading`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md).

```js
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing it @Christos. I have a similar custom component but wanted to overwrite the material ui component itself to achieve it as I don't want to import one specific component from a different path (not from "@material-ui" but some local folder) as it breaks the consistency and I want it to be a global change/theme in my codebase. I have added it to the question as well. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome @RahulGandhi. IMO you are overcomplicating things for not good reasons. This is how React works, we create componets and we override these components to create new ones. Even if you manage to achieve the MUI module type/interface to work, how are you going to implement your `fontSize` logic? Won't you create a local file to do that? Also, this kind of type manipulation does not help with consistency at all and instead it will create confusion and inconsistency not only to other developers that will come across your code in the future, but even to yourself.

Comment: Thankyou for sharing your views @Christos. I am working on creating a custom theme for the material-ui components used in the codebase and as a part of it, wanted to extend the button component to support the different variants. 

Regarding the `fontSize` logic, obvio I am going to tackle it in local css. I understand it might sound a little complex, but in reality, it's actually simplifying the codebase. 

There is a theme folder which does all the necessary customisation to the material-ui components. And that's how they suggest it well. https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/

Comment: @ChristosLytras - is the ButtonProps documented somewhere? I'm looking for the equivalent for the Radio Button props.

Comment: @jbyrd you can check the [official MUI documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/radio/#props) on the Radio component API and the source code on Github of the [`Radio.d.ts`](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-material/src/Radio/Radio.d.ts#L12).

Answer (score 4):

With Mui5 use

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button as MuiButton, ButtonProps } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

import { ITheme } from '../../mytheme';

export interface IButton extends Omit<ButtonProps, 'size'> {
  size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large' | 'huge';
  theme?: ITheme;
}

const Button: React.FC<IButton> = styled(MuiButton, {
  skipSx: true,
  skipVariantsResolver: true,
})<IButton>(({ theme }) => {
  return {//..add your styleoverrides here! or use a theming only approach};
});
```

Theming only without nesting MuiComponents follow https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#adding-new-component-variants

```js
declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
  interface ButtonPropsVariantOverrides {
   size: 'large' | 'small' | 'likemoon | 'whatsoever';
  }
}
```

cheers

Comment: This is very informative, thx for sharing

Comment: Why import Button `as MuiButton`?

Comment: @jbyrd because his customized component name is `Button` (`const Button: React.FC<IButton> = styled(...)`), there can't be two things with the same name inside the same scope.