# Extend MUI components from theme provider

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Currently I'm wondering about if there is the possibility of extending components, by adding new props directly from the theme provider.

For example, let's take the `IconButton` component, I want to add `square` prop to this component

```js
import { Components, Theme } from '@mui/material';

export const MuiIconButton: Components<Theme>['MuiIconButton'] = {
  defaultProps: {
    square: true
  },
  styleOverrides: {
    root: ({ ownerState }) => ({
      //here I would like to access the square prop
      borderRadius: ownerState.square ? 0 : 50,
    })
  }
};

declare module '@mui/material/IconButton' {
  interface IconButtonPropsOverrides {
    square: boolean;
  }
}
```

By taking a look into `IconButton.d.ts` from MUI,

```
export interface IconButtonPropsColorOverrides {}

export interface IconButtonPropsSizeOverrides {}
```

There is no override for props available...

My question is if there is any possibility of adding this override without having to alter the MUI code base. Is there a general approach over this?

Thanks

Comment: A similar question was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67690073/15814542

Comment: @m4china - it's similar but not the same `ButtonPropsVariantOverrides` exists as there are the ones listed above. I want to extend the base one not the ones that are already available

Comment: I want somehow to extend the `IconButtonProps` from the theme / module declaration