# How to extend TS interface for (MUI) React Component using styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I've been trying to figure out how to resolve this overload issue and so far no dice. I am using Typescript, Styled-components, and material-ui. I am using `styled(MUIButton)` to build off of the native MUI `Button`. Through console.logs I can see my props passing into the component, however I don't know how to set the typing so the overload error goes away.

any thoughts?

relevant articles: [How to extend props for Material-UI components using Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152782/how-to-extend-props-for-material-ui-components-using-typescript)

error:

[image]

code:

```
import { default as MUIButton, ButtonProps } from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';
import { darken } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

interface IButton extends ButtonProps {
  format?: 'primary' | 'secondary';
  variant?: 'contained' | 'outlined' | 'text';
  label: string;
}

const Button = ({ format, variant, label }: IButton): JSX.Element => (
  <StyledButton format={format} variant={variant}>
    {label}
  </StyledButton>
);

Button.defaultProps = {
  format: 'primary',
  variant: 'contained',
};

export default Button;

const StyledButton = styled(MUIButton)<IButton>`
  //? contained variant (default)
  ${({ format, theme }) => `
  background-color: ${
    format === 'primary'
      ? theme.palette.colors.main
      : theme.palette.colors.secondary
  };
  color: ${theme.palette.font.secondary};
  font-weight: ${theme.agnosticStyles.font.weight.bold};
  padding: .7rem 4rem;
  &:hover {
    background-color: ${darken(theme.palette.colors.main, 0.2)};
  }
  `}
...
}
```

Comment: pls provide version of packages

Comment: its a new project so its all the latest versions

Comment: it throws an errors in ts playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `format` is a custom property and you need to pass it as argument to `StyleButton` element.

As you already created the `IButton` interface, you can use it like:

```js
const StyledButton = styled(MUIButton)<IButton>`
   ${props => console.log(props)}
   ...
`;
```

With the above code you will need to also set the `label` in your interface as nullable (if you don't do it, you will get an error `Property 'label' is missing in type`):

```js
interface IButton extends ButtonProps {
  format?: "primary" | "secondary";
  variant?: "contained" | "outlined" | "text";
  label?: string;
}

const Button = ({ format, variant, label }: IButton): JSX.Element => (
  <StyledButton format={format} variant={variant}>
    {label}
  </StyledButton>
);

<Button label={"test"} format={"primary"} variant={"contained"} />
```

Another approach is to set your Button as a `FunctionComponnent` and then, you won't need the `label` property anymore and you can use `children` instead:

```js
interface IButton extends ButtonProps {
  format?: "primary" | "secondary";
  variant?: "contained" | "outlined" | "text";  
}

const StyledButton = styled(MUIButton)<IButton>`
   ...
`;

const Button: React.FC<IButton> = ({ format, variant, children }) => (
   <StyledButton format={format} variant={variant}>
      {children}
   </StyledButton>
);

<Button format={"secondary"} variant={"text"}>
   Test
</Button>
```

You can check more about custom props in styled-components [here](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#using-custom-props)

**Updated**

If you replace `format` with `color` in `<StyledButton>`, you will get the desire button style.

```js
interface IButton extends ButtonProps {
  format?: "primary" | "secondary";
  variant?: "contained" | "outlined" | "text";  
}

const StyledButton = styled(MUIButton)<IButton>`
   ...
`;

const Button: React.FC<IButton> = ({ format, variant, children }) => (
   
   // ******
   // HERE'S THE TRICK -> INSTEAD FORMAT, YOU SHOULD SET COLOR
   // ******
   <StyledButton color={format} variant={variant}>
      {children}
   </StyledButton>
);

<Button variant={"contained"} format={"primary"}>
   primary
</Button>
<Button variant={"outlined"} format={"secondary"}>
   secondary
</Button>
```

Comment: Hi Luis, thanks for the thorough answer. I updated my styled-component part to have an `<IButton>` type. However, the underlying material-ui `<Button>` that I'm building off of, doesn't have the `format` property on it. I'm curious how I could append that new `format` property to the already existing button to resolve the TS error.

Comment: When you say about the format, do you mean the style color button?  You can accomplish that just replacing `format` by `color`. I'll include an example on the answer.

Comment: thanks again for the feedback, in this case i'm actually referring to adding a _new_ property to the Button called "format". `format` has two values: primary or secondary, it's used to determine multiple styles that will be implemented in the styled-components. `format` does  not exist natively on the MUI Button since I just created it.

The screenshot in the initial post shows the only error thats coming up and I believe it's typescript saying "hey format doesnt exist on the button". I can't figure out how to get that typing on the button to resolve the TS complaint

Comment: I've added a bit more to the initial post showing the styled-components intention for the "format" property and how it's used to apply styles through a ternary (in this case).

Comment: Sorry, I seem to be bombarding you with comments. However, I think I resolved it. I applied your `{children}` approach and the errors all went away. So after exploring the error some more I think I was chasing after a red herring. The issue had to do with my `label`, if I make it a conditional and provide a default value that seems to work as well. `Property 'label' is missing in type '{ children: string; color?: "inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "default"; disabled?: boolean; disableElevation?: ...` is the error that appeared. I'm not sure why it's appearing though. Label is in `IButton`

Answer (score 3):

It's not completely clear what your `StyledButton` component looks like. Original [`Button`](https://material-ui.com/api/button/) from `@material-ui/core` does not accept `format` property. And that's exactly what this error is about.

If you're somehow consume this property right in your `StyledButton` you should type it accordingly:

```ts
const StyledButton = styled(MUIButton)<{format?: 'primary' | 'secondary'}>``;
```

Though maybe you're looking for the `color` property the original `Button` accepts and that may accept both `primary` and `secondary` values.

Comment: that's correct, it doesnt have the `format` property on it. I essentially want to append that property to the already existing material ui `Button`