# Is there a way to augment @mui/material Box typed props depending on the component tag passed?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to create a Box component with @mui/material which would add the needed props when i pass the prop, for example `component='img'` so the wrapper would now accept thinkgs like `alt` and `src`. But if i dont pass component it just defaults to `div` properties.

Here's a code example of what i want to achieve:

```
import {Box, BoxPropx} from '@mui/material'

interface MyBox extends BoxProps {
 someCustomProps: string;
 ...
}

export const MyBoxComponent: FC<MyBox> (props) => <Box {...props} />
```

And here i want to use the component, provide for example the `component='img'` prop and i would like the types to automatically extend themselves to accept for example `alt='alt text'` but i can't figure out how to do that

```
 <MyBoxComponent component='img' src={...} alt='alt text' /> // Here alt is underlined as not an expected property.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66123108/4774045). The only difference is that the example is with `Button` instead of `Box`

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto It seems to work nicely :) I'm pretty sure I tried this before but I might have messed up some small part of it, thanks!